# Paypal IPN issue - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal sandox to test the payment gateway. The issue is in IPN code, which is called after successful payment. The code I am using was working perfectly and suddenly stopped working since last month. I am not sure what happened, its exactly the same code provided by paypal on their github repository. Can somebody please guide me in right direction ?

Here's the code I am using for IPN controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Post back to either sandbox or live
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    //string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);
    strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {
        //check the payment_status is Completed
        //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        //process payment
    }
    else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
    {
        //log for manual investigation
    }
    else
    {
        //Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
    }
    return View();
}
```

The error message says:

> The request was aborted: **Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

It breaks on this line

```
 //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
 StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

I have searched existing posts related to this error, but they are long dated back. But I have started experiencing this error since last month. So, may be some breaking changes from paypal and I am not aware of. Can anybody please help me here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following above your line:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);
```

I've been working with a PayPal (NVP/Signature) Express Checkout integration and have been hit with this SSL/TLS error.

Nothing I did seemed to get around it but then I found the following code to add above my request. For reference, I'm using MVC3/.NET 4 so Tls1.2 isn't available to me by default (like in .NET 4.5 +). This first three lines of this code gets around that. I hope it helps people!

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is true if you are using "signature" authentication:

Point is that few weeks ago endpoint https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ stopped working. Now should use this one instead: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

To do that I changed endpoints for sandbox in "paypal-endpoint.xml" found in PayPal's SDK. Download SDK, find "paypal-endpoint.xml", find Sandbox section and change addresses to be "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/". Then recompile the paypal_base.dll and use it

Here is posted very similar solution, but XMLs are published in web.config: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox/c-sdk-sandbox-three-token-endpoint

More info about current PayPal's endpoints: https://www.x.com/content/api-endpoints